# Unable to get front-end Profile form to save changes

Tags: users, frontend

This is my first attempt at setting up a front-end form so my users can update their profile information.  The profile is using the VZ Address plugin for the address field.

When I go to the page, it pulls all of my details in.  When I update something on the front-end and submit, I get a confirmation message ("Your profile has been updated.") that it went fine, but the fields are not updated. I have template debugging turned on and there are no errors.

Here is my form

```
{% block content %}
<div class="cell small-12 medium-9">
    {% if craft.session.getFlash('notice') == 'User saved.'|t %}
    <div class="grid-x">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="callout alert">Your profile has been updated.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        {{ getCsrfInput() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/clients/account/profile">
        <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

        {% macro errorList(errors) %}
            {% if errors %}
                <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endmacro %}
        {% from _self import errorList %}

        <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
            <fieldset class="cell small-12">
                <label for="firstName">Mailing Name</label><input type="text" id="currentUser.address.name" name="fields[currentUser.address.name]" value="{{ currentUser.address.name }}">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
            <fieldset class="cell small-12">
                <label for="firstName">Address</label><input type="text" id="currentUser.address.street" name="fields[currentUser.address.street]" value="{{ currentUser.address.street }}">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
            <fieldset class="cell small-12">
                <label for="firstName">Address 2</label><input type="text" id="currentUser.address.street2" name="fields[currentUser.address.street2]" value="{{ currentUser.address.street2 }}">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
        <fieldset class="cell small-6">
            <label for="city">City</label><input type="text" id="currentUser.address.city" name="fields[currentUser.address.city]" value="{{ currentUser.address.city }}">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="cell small-3">
            <label for="region">State
            <select>
                <option value="AL"{%if currentUser.address.region=="AL" %} selected{% endif %}>Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK"{%if currentUser.address.region=="AK" %} selected{% endif %}>Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ"{%if currentUser.address.region=="AZ" %} selected{% endif %}>Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR"{%if currentUser.address.region=="AR" %} selected{% endif %}>Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA"{%if currentUser.address.region=="CA" %} selected{% endif %}>California</option>
                <option value="CO"{%if currentUser.address.region=="CO" %} selected{% endif %}>Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT"{%if currentUser.address.region=="CT" %} selected{% endif %}>Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DE"{%if currentUser.address.region=="DE" %} selected{% endif %}>Delaware</option>
                <option value="DC"{%if currentUser.address.region=="DC" %} selected{% endif %}>District Of Columbia</option>
                <option value="FL"{%if currentUser.address.region=="FL" %} selected{% endif %}>Florida</option>
                <option value="GA"{%if currentUser.address.region=="GA" %} selected{% endif %}>Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI"{%if currentUser.address.region=="HI" %} selected{% endif %}>Hawaii</option>
                <option value="ID"{%if currentUser.address.region=="ID" %} selected{% endif %}>Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL"{%if currentUser.address.region=="IL" %} selected{% endif %}>Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN"{%if currentUser.address.region=="IN" %} selected{% endif %}>Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA"{%if currentUser.address.region=="IA" %} selected{% endif %}>Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS"{%if currentUser.address.region=="KS" %} selected{% endif %}>Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY"{%if currentUser.address.region=="KY" %} selected{% endif %}>Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA"{%if currentUser.address.region=="LA" %} selected{% endif %}>Louisiana</option>
                <option value="ME"{%if currentUser.address.region=="ME" %} selected{% endif %}>Maine</option>
                <option value="MD"{%if currentUser.address.region=="MD" %} selected{% endif %}>Maryland</option>
                <option value="MA"{%if currentUser.address.region=="MA" %} selected{% endif %}>Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MI"{%if currentUser.address.region=="MI" %} selected{% endif %}>Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN"{%if currentUser.address.region=="MN" %} selected{% endif %}>Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MS"{%if currentUser.address.region=="MS" %} selected{% endif %}>Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO"{%if currentUser.address.region=="MO" %} selected{% endif %}>Missouri</option>
                <option value="MT"{%if currentUser.address.region=="MT" %} selected{% endif %}>Montana</option>
                <option value="NE"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NE" %} selected{% endif %}>Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NV"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NV" %} selected{% endif %}>Nevada</option>
                <option value="NH"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NH" %} selected{% endif %}>New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NJ" %} selected{% endif %}>New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NM" %} selected{% endif %}>New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NY"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NY" %} selected{% endif %}>New York</option>
                <option value="NC"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NC" %} selected{% endif %}>North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND"{%if currentUser.address.region=="ND" %} selected{% endif %}>North Dakota</option>
                <option value="OH"{%if currentUser.address.region=="OH" %} selected{% endif %}>Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK"{%if currentUser.address.region=="OK" %} selected{% endif %}>Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR"{%if currentUser.address.region=="OR" %} selected{% endif %}>Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA"{%if currentUser.address.region=="PA" %} selected{% endif %}>Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="RI"{%if currentUser.address.region=="RI" %} selected{% endif %}>Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC"{%if currentUser.address.region=="SC" %} selected{% endif %}>South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD"{%if currentUser.address.region=="SD" %} selected{% endif %}>South Dakota</option>
                <option value="TN"{%if currentUser.address.region=="TN" %} selected{% endif %}>Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX"{%if currentUser.address.region=="TX" %} selected{% endif %}>Texas</option>
                <option value="UT"{%if currentUser.address.region=="UT" %} selected{% endif %}>Utah</option>
                <option value="VT"{%if currentUser.address.region=="VT" %} selected{% endif %}>Vermont</option>
                <option value="VA"{%if currentUser.address.region=="VA" %} selected{% endif %}>Virginia</option>
                <option value="WA"{%if currentUser.address.region=="WA" %} selected{% endif %}>Washington</option>
                <option value="WV"{%if currentUser.address.region=="WV" %} selected{% endif %}>West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WI"{%if currentUser.address.region=="WI" %} selected{% endif %}>Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WY"{%if currentUser.address.region=="WY" %} selected{% endif %}>Wyoming</option>
                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                <option value="" disabled>-- US Outlying Territories --</option>
                <option value="AS"{%if currentUser.address.region=="AS" %} selected{% endif %}>American Samoa (AS)</option>
                <option value="GU"{%if currentUser.address.region=="GU" %} selected{% endif %}>Guam (GU)</option>
                <option value="MP"{%if currentUser.address.region=="MP" %} selected{% endif %}>Northern Mariana Islands (MP)</option>
                <option value="PR"{%if currentUser.address.region=="PR" %} selected{% endif %}>Puerto Rico (PR)</option>
                <option value="UM"{%if currentUser.address.region=="UM" %} selected{% endif %}>United States Minor Outlying Islands (UM)</option>
                <option value="VI"{%if currentUser.address.region=="VI" %} selected{% endif %}>Virgin Islands (VI)</option>
                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                <option value="" disabled>----- Canada Province -----</option>
                <option value="AB"{%if currentUser.address.region=="AB" %} selected{% endif %}>Alberta</option>
                <option value="BC"{%if currentUser.address.region=="BC" %} selected{% endif %}>British Columbia</option>
                <option value="MB"{%if currentUser.address.region=="MB" %} selected{% endif %}>Manitoba</option>
                <option value="NB"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NB" %} selected{% endif %}>New Brunswick</option>
                <option value="NL"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NL" %} selected{% endif %}>Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
                <option value="NS"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NS" %} selected{% endif %}>Nova Scotia</option>
                <option value="NT"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NT" %} selected{% endif %}>Northwest Territories</option>
                <option value="NU"{%if currentUser.address.region=="NU" %} selected{% endif %}>Nunavut</option>
                <option value="ON"{%if currentUser.address.region=="ON" %} selected{% endif %}>Ontario</option>
                <option value="PE"{%if currentUser.address.region=="PE" %} selected{% endif %}>Prince Edward Island</option>
                <option value="QC"{%if currentUser.address.region=="QC" %} selected{% endif %}>Quebec</option>
                <option value="SK"{%if currentUser.address.region=="SK" %} selected{% endif %}>Saskatchewan</option>
                <option value="YT"{%if currentUser.address.region=="YT" %} selected{% endif %}>Yukon</option>
            </select>
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="cell small-3">
            <label for="postalCode">Zip Code</label><input type="text" id="address.postalCode" name="fields[address.postalCode]" value="{{ currentUser.address.postalCode }}">
        </fieldset>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Profile">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

If I update the information in the CP, then the new information is displayed on the front end.

The "action" value of "users/saveUser" - is this something that I need to create, or is it a system file?

I'm stumped.

Comment: What happens if you try using bracket instead of dot syntax for your field names? For example, `...type="text" name="fields[address][name]"...`?

Comment: Same - tells me that it updated successfully, but still the old information.

Comment: Actually, this does work for my custom fields (not for the built-in fields though like firstName, lastName, email).

Comment: I figured out the "built-in" fields.  If you can add your comment as an answer I will give you credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The First Name and other built-in fields are kind of special. You can access them directly without having to prefix them with `fields`.

To use other custom fields, try using bracket syntax instead of dot syntax.

For example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">
        Street Address<span><small><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></small></span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="fields[address][name]" class="form-control" {%- if currentUser is defined %} value="{{ currentUser.address.name }}"{% endif -%}>
    {{ currentUser is defined and currentUser ? errorList(currentUser.getErrors('address.name')) }}
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think that instead of

```
fields[currentUser.address.city]
```

you need to refer to the fields like this

```
fields[address.city]
```

or even

```
fields[address][city]
```

perhaps even

```
fields[0][address][city]
```

In retrospect, this answer isn't very helpful.

Comment: It turns out, for my custom fields this works <input type="text" id="city" name="fields[address][city]" value="{{ currentUser.address.city }}">.  Technically Damon's "answer" is correct but thank you so much for chiming in!